# How to handle Quiet, Check, and Message in one InputField run?

Tags: quiet, check, message-code

When I execute the command statement in InputField, I want to output the execution result or message.

```
Attributes[MessagedQ] = {HoldAll};                
MessagedQ[eval_] := Check[eval, $failed] === $failed;         
MessagedQ[eval_, messages_] := Check[eval, $failed, messages] === $failed;
SetAttributes[GeneratedMessageList, HoldFirst];
GeneratedMessageList[expr_] := Block[{res, $Messages = {OpenWrite[]}, $MessagePrePrint = 
 TextString},WithCleanup[
expr; res = Close[$Messages[[1]]];
Import[res, "Lines"],
DeleteFile[res]] ];
Manipulate[Check[ToExpression@in, GeneratedMessageList[ToExpression@in]], 
Style[ Control@{{in, Null}, InputField[#, Boxes] &, ImageSize -> {600, 50}} , 20] ]
```

I must maintain the InputField[#,Boxes] format above.

[image]

Now, I've entered a command. I hope the message will only be in Manipulate.
So I modified the code.

```
Manipulate[Quiet@Check[ToExpression@in, GeneratedMessageList[ToExpression@in]],  
Style[ Control@{{in, Null}, InputField[#, Boxes] &, ImageSize -> {600, 50}} , 20] ]
```

[image]

I did Quiet@Check[...] and all the messages didn't appear. I corrected it again.

```
Manipulate[msg = GeneratedMessageList[ToExpression@in];
If[FailureQ[Quiet@Check[ToExpression@in, $Failed]], msg, ToExpression@in ], 
Style[ Control@{{in, Null}, InputField[#, Boxes] &, ImageSize -> {600, 50}} , 20] ]
```

[image]

This time, the message appears only in Manipulate. However, there is one important problem.

The command(=in) runs 3 times, increasing the ++i value by 3.

I want to get this result as the only one executed.

Like the Mathematica In[#], Out[#] system. Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: `msg = GeneratedMessageList[ expr = ToExpression@in];` and use `expr` later?

Comment: First of all, I would like to implement it on the premise that expr has no additional use. 
Ultimately, depending on the format of in, it must be processed in two ways using If.  

For example, the process I have to deal with requires two runs: ToExpression@FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket@ToExpression@in and ToExpression@ToExpression@in. 

Here too, a problem of ++i occurs due to overlapping execution.

Comment: If you give me an idea of the first problem, I will apply it and try to solve the second problem.

Comment: For your information, it is the result of my work so far.
http://naver.me/FFSIHR4D